# How do I check for this odd space character - " " in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I wrote some RegEx to play with spaces in strings, and it works beautifully, except for when I come across this character: " " instead of " ". You probably think I'm crazy, but apparently they're different. Check out this RegEx app (oddly enough, it often crashes it):

When I use the weird space:

[image]

When I use a normal space:

[image]

As you can see, there are many more spaces detected here, but it doesn't detect the weird spaces.

What is this space? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: The spaces in your post *are* the same.  Can you post the correct (presumably unicode) one?

Comment: You will have to view the raw text in Hex Mode to ASCII number.

Comment: There are many ascii characters that have no visible character art (essentially looks like a space) that are not the actual space (ascii 32) character.

Comment: I would guess it's some type of Unicode Space like non-breaking space (U+00A0).

Comment: Looks like you have some word-processed prose there. Is it possible the weird spaces you are seeing are non-breaking spaces. so maybe your wp or text layout app has a special space character that will not be replaced by a line end. e.g the phrase "add up to a movie star" might be split over two lines, but the weird space is saying the line break should not happen between the "to" and "a". I don't know what app you've used to create the text, but maybe there's a setting in that app to not include these non-breaking spaces. Oops  Jeffery Thomas has entered the same reply a few seconds before me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode has a lot of different [space characters](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html).  The space you posted in your question -- in both the title and the body -- is a regular ASCII space, good old U+0020.

If you want to check exactly what you've copied onto your clipboard, you can run the command [`pbpaste(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html) on Mac OS X.  For example, if you copied a non-breaking space (U+00A0), you could identify it like so:

```
# Write pasteboard contents to stdout, convert from UTF-8 to UTF-32 for easy
# code point identification, then hex dump the contents
$ pbpaste | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-32be | hexdump -C
00000000  00 00 00 a0                                       |....|
00000004
```

Depending on the regex engine you're using, it may not support them all, especially if you use the `\s` character class.  If you want to be sure to match the space character you have, then include it explicitly in your character class, e.g. `[\s<YOURSPACEHERE>]`, where `<YOURSPACEHERE>` is copy+pasted from the character you want to match.

Comment: It is indeed an a0 according to that command, thank you. I'll try the [\s...] suggestion. :)

Comment: And hey, Xcode even seems to have a special symbol for it. http://i.imgur.com/a6G4gQO.png

Answer (score 1):

Try "\p{Z}" for your regular expression. It's the unicode property for any kind of whitespace or invisible separator.

See: [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

---

Just as a test of my answer, I constructed the following unit test.

```
- (void)testPattern
{
    NSString *string = @"xxx\u00A0yyy";
    NSString *pattern = @"\\p{Z}";
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:NULL];

    NSUInteger number = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    STAssertEquals(number, 1U, @"");
}
```

Comment: Switch away from PHP regular expressions.

Comment: Sorry not a complete thought, inside Objective-C, is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

They're probably non-breaking spaces, seeing as all the lines end with spaces that are matched by **\s** rather than these mystery spaces. Try matching `\0xA0`.

Comment: Apologies, it is A0, but for whatever reason the app couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can match Unicode characters with \x{NNNN}, where NNNN is the Hexa code of the character. See [ICU User Guide](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).